# Run Ostendo Script from a batch file (or scheduled Task)

Tags: batch-file, pascal

I have written a script in Ostendo that sends an email. This works fine when running the script from within Ostendo. But it doesn't work when I try to run the script from a batch file:

Ostendo script:

```
Const
TheEmailHostName = 'intmail.company.com';
TheEmailSenderAddress = 'simon.k@company.com';
TheUserEmail= 'Email Message Test';
TheRecipientsEmail = 'simon.k@company.com';

Var
TheEmailSubject, TheEmailBody:                   String;

Begin
TheEmailSubject := 'In stock quantity of Item code CUSTOMPURCHASE does not equal zero';
TheEmailBody := 'Please correct this so the quantity equals zero. Please refer to the SOP which can be found in ...';

SendEmailMessage(TheEmailHostName,TheEmailSenderAddress,TheRecipientsEmail,TheEmailSubject,TheEmailBody);
//Showmessage('There are ' + QueryResult + ' in stock of CUSTOMPURCHASE')


End
```

.

The batchfile is:

```
Z:\ostendo.exe STARTUPID:Demo Script=SK - Test Email
```

"Demo" is the name of the Ostendo database;
"SK - Test Email" is the name of the script in Ostendo

No error comes up. It just doesn't send the email. It doesn't work from the desktop or the network.

Comment: Ostendo environment variables and/or working dir come to mind as possible causes

Comment: The spaces in your script name are causing a problem. They're being interpreted as three or four separate values, rather than one. You can try either surrounding it with double-quotes (`Script="SK - Test Email"`) or renaming the script to something without spaces (`Script=SKTestEMail`).

Comment: That was the problem (spaces). So removed the spaces. Didn't try double quotes. THANKS.